# Inheritance of Overloaded assignment Operator

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

**C++ Complete Reference says ,"Except for the = operator,operator functions are inherited by a derive class."**

But i cannt understand the behaviour of the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    class b{
        int i;
        public:
            int operator=(b parm){
                cout<<"base overload";
            };
    };
    class d: public b{
        int j;
        public:
    };



    b inst1,inst11;
    d inst2,inst22;
    int a;

   inst1=inst11;    //works because assignment operator  is overloaded for b

   inst2=inst22;  //If =operator function is not inherited then why does it output "base oberload"

   inst1=inst2;    //works because assignment overloaded for b

 // inst2=inst11;      //But if b was inherited then this should also work but it doesnt


}
```

**I am expecting two output statements "base overload" but it is outputting three**  Why?? this is driving me nuts

Answer (score 0):

`operator=` is not inherited. But the compiler will [generate implicitly](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Implicitly-defined_copy_assignment_operator) an `operator=` for class `d`, which invokes `b::operator=` for the assignment of the base subobject.

> the operator performs member-wise copy assignment of the object's bases and non-static members, in their initialization order, using built-in assignment for the scalars and copy assignment operator for class types.

then

> ```
> inst2=inst22;  //If =operator function is not inherited then why does it output "base oberload"
> ```

The generated `d::operator=` is called here; inside which `b::operator=` is invoked.

> ```
> inst1=inst2;    //works because assignment overloaded for b
> ```

`b::operator=` is called here, it expects `b` as the argument and `inst2` could be implicitly converted to the base class `b`.

> ```
> // inst2=inst11;      //But if b was inherited then this should also work but it doesnt
> ```

`d::operator=` is tried to be called here, it expects `d` as the argument but `inst11` can't be implicitly converted to the derived class `d`.